# Find the bilinear form associated to a quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Let $$Q(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1^2+2x_2^2+3x_3^2+4x_4^2+5x_1x_2+6x_1x_3+7x_1x_4+8x_2x_3+9x_2x_4+10x_3x_4.$$

How can I find $f$ bilinear s.t. $Q(x)=f(x,x)$ ?

It's written in my book that if $Q(x)=\sum_{i,j}\alpha _{ij}x_ix_j$, then $$\frac{\partial q}{\partial x_i}=2\sum_{j}\alpha _{ij}x_j,$$
and thus $Mat(f)=(\alpha _{ij})$, but I don't really understand what it mean. I don't see the correlation between $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x_i}$ and $f$.

Answer (score 0):

For the correlation between $\frac{\partial Q }{\partial x_i}$ and $f$ if $Q(x)=f(x,x)$ then:
$$Q(x)=Q\left(\sum_k x_k e_k\right)=f \left(\sum_k x_k e_k, \sum_j x_j e_j \right)=\sum_{k,j} x_k x_j f(e_i,e_j)$$
so for a fixed $i$, differentiating with respect to $x_i$:
$$\frac{\partial Q }{\partial x_i}=\sum_j x_j f(e_i,e_j)+\sum_k x_k f(e_k,e_i)$$
and if you are looking for a symmetric $f$ you obtain:
$$\frac{\partial Q }{\partial x_i}=2 \sum_j x_j f(e_i,e_j)$$
and by definition:
$$Mat(f)_{i,j}=f(e_i,e_j)$$

Comment: As you said $Q(x)=\sum_{k,j}x_kx_j f(e_k,e_j)$. So I directly have $mat(f)_{i,j}=f(e_i,e_j)$. So why using the derivative ?

Comment: Indeed there is no need to use the derivative :-). The advantage I can see is that this is more "classic" to find the coefficients of a linear operator than the ones of a quadratic form...

Answer (score 0):

the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc} 
2 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
5 & 4 & 8 & 9 \\
6 & 8 & 6 & 10 \\
7 & 9 & 10 & 8
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Note $H^T = H.$

If I write column vectors $x$ and $y$ with four entries each, then $q(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^THx $ and $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} x^THy =  \frac{1}{2} y^THx  $

Comment: why do we use derivative ? As written, $Q(x)=\sum_{k,j}x_kx_j f(e_k,e_j)$. So I directly have $mat(f)_{i,j}=f(e_i,e_j)$. So why using the derivative ?